# Running T4 templates under source control (TFS)

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, version-control, t4

**Background**

I frequently have to adapt a `.tt` file (T4 templates) that generates an `.xsd` file. That's done by changing a `.txt` source file and starting *'Run Custom Tool'*.

**The issue**

When I do a change, I will do an automatic check out of my `.txt` that is used as base file. The `.xsd` however, is not checked out. Running the T4 likes this will generate a not-very-descriptive error, if the output target isn't checked out as well. It's easy to miss, especially if you have other errors, giving you the false sense of security that your T4 has run correctly.

**The question**

Is there a way to set things up so that all T4 dependencies are automatically checked out upon editing?

Answer (score 2):

If the `.xsd` is a generated file, it should not be under source control, since it is a result of the build process.

I think that the best thing to do here would be to exclude/ignore the generated file in your source control system.

*Just as an idea*, because this is probably very dependent on the SC tool you use (I'm using SVN which seems to behave correctly in this case), you could try to modify (manually) your project file to say that your `.tt` file is dependent on the `.txt` file:

```
<Content Include="YourT4File.tt">
  <Generator>TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor</Generator>
  <LastGenOutput>YourT4File.xsd</LastGenOutput>
  <DependentUpon>YourTextFile.txt</DependentUpon>
</Content>
```

Just try to add the `<DependentUpon>` node...

Comment: That would be my preference indeed, but it's a legacy issue. Whenever possible we will address this, but that's not nearby.

Comment: @Spikee: your problem is that the change in the generated file is not caused by a change in the T4 file.

Comment: I'm under TFS. Looks like something that could work, I'll look into it!